# How to store / re-roll dices in Dice Roll simulator in C

Tags: c, dice

I have searched all around when trying to search for previous questions and answers, but I can't seem to find what I am looking for. At least not for plain C, so here I go.

As part of a University Task, I am writing a Roll Dice simulator in C. I have managed the initial task to make it possible to choose up to three players/users, and I have made it possible to roll the dices three times for each player/user.

Most probably it is possible to make it even easier (with less code), but so far it is working. The next part of the task is to make it possible to save dices, and only reroll some of them. I was thinking of making integers/variables like p1_keep1 (Player 1 Dice 1), p1_keep2 (Player 1 Dice 2), and so forth, but I am really stuck in how to implement it in the code to make it possible to save some dices and reroll the rest.

I thought about making a second loop under RollingDiceP1, RollingDiceP2 and RollingDiceP3 (see the code below for refference) where the dices are rolled, but I am unsure how to implement it, without making ittoo complicated. I tried with a while loop inside the do-while loop, but it became so complicated with ten of nested 'if else', so I deleted it, convinced there has to bea better way, though I have not manage to find/spot it yet.

In order to find a solution, is there something I can do to make my initial code "easier", or in other words, can I get the same result with less code?
If I could compress the code somehow, maybe it would be easier to spot/see the solution on how to save some of the dices, while re-rolling the rest.

As I said above, I did try a while loop inside the do-while loop, but it quickly became so vast and complicated that I could not manage to tag along, and I am convinced that there are better ways, though I have not managed to spot them yet. Any tip/help or push in the right direction would be appreciated. As you might spot in the code below, this is my third week with c, and as part-time student I have not been able to work that much with c yet. I am convinced there has to be a loop of some kind though, just not sure if while, do-while or for, is the most suitable one.

This is the challenge I am currently stuck in:
*Challenge: Future implement your dice program so that the user can save some dice, and then only rolling the amount of dice that they haven't saved.Like you would normally do in Yahtzee.*

My present code, looks like this, and help/tip or push in the right direction are highly appreciated:

```
/*
Author: Thorbjørn Elvestad
Student ID: XXXXX
E-mail: XXXXXXXXXXXXX@XXXXX.XXX

This is a Roll the Dice (for Yahtzee) simulation, where the computer rolls the dice,
and present the result to the users. Only the result is presented. The
user does not physically see the dice rolled. There can be a set number
of players, and each players got three rolls each before the next player
role.

This is Activity 1 of the Week 3 weekly activity.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

/* Setting all functions to be used in the program */
void players (void);
void RollingDiceP1 (void);
void RollingDiceP2 (void);
void RollingDiceP3 (void);

/* Loading all global variables to be available for all functions in the program */

    /* Setting variable for amount of players */
    int numberPlayers = 0;
    /* Setting variables for player 1-3 dices */
    int p1_dice1 = 0, p1_dice2 = 0, p1_dice3 = 0, p1_dice4 = 0, p1_dice5 = 0;
    int p2_dice1 = 0, p2_dice2 = 0, p2_dice3 = 0, p2_dice4 = 0, p2_dice5 = 0;
    int p3_dice1 = 0, p3_dice2 = 0, p3_dice3 = 0, p3_dice4 = 0, p3_dice5 = 0;

    /* Seting variable for allowed rounds of rolling the dice */
    int rolldice_counter = 1;

    char press_enter;



/*Initiating the main function */
int main(void)
{
    /* Loading the Random Number generator */
    srand(time(NULL));

    printf("Howdy! \n");
    printf("\n Welcome to the Roll a Dice Yahtzee Simulator, \n");

    /* Loading functions for choosing amount of players */
    players();
    printf("Let us roll some dice! \n");
    RollingDiceP1();                                                                                           

    /* Checking if there are more players waiting for their turn */
    while (1)
    {
        if (numberPlayers == 3)
        {
            printf("\n \n \n \n Player two, stay tuned... \n \n");
            RollingDiceP2();
            printf("\n \n \n \n Player three, stay tuned... \n \n");
            RollingDiceP3();
            break;
        }


    else if (numberPlayers == 2){
            printf("\n \n \n \n Player 2, stay tuned... \n");
            RollingDiceP2 ();}
    else
        printf("No more players waiting for rolling their dice, thanks for playing! \n");
        break;
    }
    printf("No more players waiting for rolling their dices, thanks for playing! \n");

return 0;
}


/* Lets choose how many players to use the Yahtzee Roll Dice Simulator */
void players()
{
    printf("Please type how many players (1-3):");

    while (1)
    {
     scanf("%d", &numberPlayers);
     if (numberPlayers == 1)
        {
            printf("You have selected %d players! ", numberPlayers);
            break;
        }
    else if (numberPlayers == 2)
        {
            printf("You have selected %d players! ", numberPlayers);
            break;
        }
    else if (numberPlayers == 3)
        {
            printf("You have selected %d players! ", numberPlayers);
            break;
        }
    else printf("Invalid number of players, please choose 1-3 players:");

    }
}

/* Rolling dices for player 1 */
void RollingDiceP1()
{
    do
        {
        /* Rolling the dices, and fetching random numbers between 1-6 for Player 1 dices */
        printf("\n Hold tight player 1, I am rolling your dices: \n");
        p1_dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p1_dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p1_dice3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p1_dice4 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p1_dice5 = rand() % 6 + 1;

        /* Showing the result for player 1 */
        printf("Your dices show:\n Dice 1: %d \n Dice 2: %d \n Dice 3: %d \n Dice 4: %d \n Dice 5: %d \n \n", p1_dice1, p1_dice2, p1_dice3, p1_dice4, p1_dice5);
        printf("This is your roll number %d of 3 rolls, press any key and enter to continue \n", rolldice_counter);
        scanf("%s", &press_enter);
        } while (++rolldice_counter <= 3); /* Ending the do-while loop when rolldice_counter reach 0 */
        rolldice_counter = 1;
}

/* Rolling dices for player 2 */
void RollingDiceP2()
{
    do
        {
        /* Rolling the dices, and fetching random numbers between 1-6 for Player 2 dices */
        printf("\n Hold tight player 2, I am rolling your dices: \n");
        p2_dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p2_dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p2_dice3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p2_dice4 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p2_dice5 = rand() % 6 + 1;

        /* Showing the result for player 2 */
        printf("Your dices show:\n Dice 1: %d \n Dice 2: %d \n Dice 3: %d \n Dice 4: %d \n Dice 5: %d \n \n", p2_dice1, p2_dice2, p2_dice3, p2_dice4, p2_dice5);
        printf("This is your roll number %d of 3 rolls, press any key and enter to continue \n", rolldice_counter);
        scanf("%s", &press_enter);
        } while (++rolldice_counter <= 3); /* Ending the do-while loop when rolldice_counter reach 0 */
        rolldice_counter = 1;
}

/* Rolling dices for player 3 */
void RollingDiceP3()
{
    do
        {
        /* Rolling the dices, and fetching random numbers between 1-6 for Player 3 dices */
        printf("\n Hold tight player 3, I am rolling your dices: \n");
        p3_dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p3_dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p3_dice3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p3_dice4 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p3_dice5 = rand() % 6 + 1;

        /* Showing the result for player 3 */
        printf("Your dices show:\n Dice 1: %d \n Dice 2: %d \n Dice 3: %d \n Dice 4: %d \n Dice 5: %d \n \n", p3_dice1, p3_dice2, p3_dice3, p3_dice4, p3_dice5);
        printf("This is your roll number %d of 3 rolls, press any key and enter to continue \n", rolldice_counter);
        scanf("%s", &press_enter);
        } while (++rolldice_counter <= 3); /* Ending the do-while loop when rolldice_counter reach 0 */
        rolldice_counter = 1;
}
```

Comment: p3_dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p3_dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p3_dice3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p3_dice4 = rand() % 6 + 1;
        p3_dice5 = rand() % 6 + 1; use a loop and an array here

Comment: There are certainly things to make this code simpler. For starters instead of having a ton of variables you could just use arrays. However as for your problem: What exactly are you struggling with? and how are you letting the players choose which dice they want to save?  Having a different array for saved dice rolls is probably part of the solution you are looking for

Comment: Instead of three copies of same function RollingDiceP1, RollingDiceP2, RollingDiceP3, use a single function and pass array parameter

Comment: I am sorry but your entire approach is wrong. You should be using an array of N dice. Then it would be simple to have other arrays holding info on each die. Right now you have three variables for each die, and the code has become unmanagable. Even better, consider an array of structs, holding information on each die. There comes a time in many projects, when you write off what you have done to experience, and start again, as the shortest path to your goal. Consider how you might rejig the code for a new game with **6** dice!

Comment: Thanks for the advise about arrays, did not think about that. As to how I let the players choose which dice to save, I used another ton of variables like: p1_save1, p1_save 2, p1_save3, p1_save4, p1_save5 etc, and tried to place a while loop inside the do-while loop, but it quickly became just to unmanagable as Weather so nicely put it:) I thank you all for your replies, I will look into arrays and most probably just start all over :)